# Monitor stays black after dedusting pc

Tags: hardware-failure

I have dedusted my Computer after it had some cooling problems. Now the monitor stays black, no BIOS.

This is my setup:

```
MB: Asus m5a97 
CPU: FX 8320 RAM: 
Corsair ddr3 2x8gb 1333MHz 
GC: nVidia 1060
```

I dont think I have a piezo, but it beeps once when I start it. I already tried all thinkable ram setups, even completely without ram, but the computer doesn't care, nothing changes. It can't be a compatibility problem, since it definitely ran before in this setup. I also tried to unplug my cpu fan too, but nothing changes. If you have any idea what I could do, feel free to post your opinion. There are no dumb answers to this problem.

Comment: If you don't see any disconnected contact, take the computer to a repairman.

Comment: How did you clean it?

Comment: Remove your rams and turn on the computer then turn off and re-insert in case this doesn’t work try removing the cmos battery for 1 minute and reinsert. Worth a shot

Answer (score 1):

#### It beeps once when I start it

Check your monitor is correctly connected and working (test on another PC).

> 1. Power Light is ON, "One short beep" from speaker but nothing shows on monitor
>
>    One short beep from speaker means device boots normally. **Please
>      confirm whether monitor is working and correctly connected to device**.

Source [[Motherboard] Nothing shows on monitor after assembling a PC, the way of identification by connecting the buzzer | Official Support | ASUS Global](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1029959/)

Comment: The monitor is working, it recognises when it gets connected to my gc and says no connection, when i unplug it from my gc. Also tested with a different monitor, same result. Hooking a different computer up to the monitor is not possible, since besides my pc I only have a Laptop, for which I dont have the necessary adapters.